# javascript take value from array

Tags: javascript, arrays, validation

```
form name="car" onsubmit="return validate()"
input type=text name=input[][] value......
```

how can I alert value from filed input that is an field array?

```
    function validate(){
    alert("meee");
    var mycar = document.car.elements(input).value; // this line does NOT want to store value in mycar
    alert(mycar);
    }
```

in this case alert box with message mee is displayed but another box that should display value mycar is not displayed.

Answer (score 1):

Well, just use square brackets:

```
document.car.elements['input[][]'].value;
```

Comment: No it doesnt work it just pass data without validation when I put above javascript this line alert("muuuu"); it will throw alert box but it wont display mycar value but it just pass values to another page without alert(mycar)... any ideas?

Comment: @user1508136 You need to post your full code; otherwise it's really hard to help you.