# javascript, take value from form

Tags: javascript, arrays, forms

```
<form name="car" onsubmit="return validate()">
<input type=text name=input[][] value="......" />
```

how can I alert value from filed input that is an field array?

```
    function validate(){
      alert("meee");
      var mycar = document.car.elements['input[][]'].value; // this line does NOT want to store value in mycar
      alert(mycar);
    }
```

in this case alert box with message mee is displayed but another box that should display value mycar is not displayed.

Comment: Why have you posted the same question again?
http://stackoverflow.com/q/15248559/672455

Comment: Works for [me](http://jsfiddle.net/wDpuX/1/) in Firefox and Chrome, actually. What browser is used?

Comment: safari, ok gonna try it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

simply assign an id or class to the input and use to access it.

As an example :

```
<input id="mycar" type="text" name=input[][] value="..." />
```

and the related JS

```
function validate() {
  var mycar = document.getElementById('mycar');
  var value = mycar.value;

}
```

if you insist on using the name, you can reference [HTML form input tag name element array with JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3234205/html-form-input-tag-name-element-array-with-javascript)